# Tomcat server is not starting in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I started a basic web application and using tomcat as server. I worked through it and when tried to run the server, the `build is successful and Process finished with exit code 0` and the server is not started. What is the reason the server is not starting ? I have the following `web.xml` file in the project. If any other file is required to answer the question, please, let me know. I also provided the project structure in the question.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNNHb.png)

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>basic-web-app</groupId>
<artifactId>basic-web-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.21</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: How are you starting tomcat?

Comment: maven projects -> tomcat7:run  from the right side of the IntelliJ

Comment: Is it CE version of licensed version? Check this thread - may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041356/intellij-and-tomcat-howto

Answer (score 3):

[Run/Debug configurations pop screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBL77.png)

Your Tomcat dependency scope is "Provided"(provided). Make sure you have enabled the **"include dependencies with *Provided* scope"** checkbox in the **"Run/Debug configurations"**

Reference for Scope tag in maven:
[What is <scope> under <dependency> in pom.xml for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975818/what-is-scope-under-dependency-in-pom-xml-for)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the right panel active?  This is usually what you see when you run a unit test.  Your project structure looks fine.

Here's how I'd start it:

- Go to Run --> Edit Configurations
- Click the + symbol under Tomcat Server to add one (Local)
- Type in something in the Name: field to distinguish it ("dev")

[image]

- Uncheck "After launch:" (optional)
- Click Deployment and click +

[image]

- Choose Artifact
- Choose the exploded war
- Click Ok
- Choose Run and "Run `dev`"

You should see your Tomcat log populating in the panel at the bottom of the window.

(Note: still evaluating, but it's a great tool!)

Answer (score 1):

add the following to your POM :
`<packaging>war</packaging>`
IDEA should automatically identify the artifact (your WAR file) to deploy. No need to manually create an artifact.

[Run app in tomcat using maven with IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057675/run-app-in-tomcat-using-maven-with-intellij)

Answer (score 0):

check port 8080 is used by any other service. If it is used, kill the other process or use different port by configuring in properties file. **mvn tomcat7:run** is the command to deploy your application into tomcat. The above configuration need to be done in **pom.xml** instead of web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have set Tomcat on your IDE correctly. This issue may happen when another process works with the port `8080` that belongs to Tomcat defaultly.

In Windows, run the following command to see what PID uses your port.

```
netstat -aon | find "8080"
```

The sample output is:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5048
TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       5048
```

Then press the `ctrl+alt+delete` and see the tab `details`. Kill all the processes with the same PID (`5048` in my example) using your port.

---

Also don't run twice your Tomcat, i.e. don't start it with `startup.bat` and in your IDE at the same time.